Exception calling TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById()
Why does the following line succeed in a .NET Console application, but fails in an ASP.NET Core WebApi application?
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Europe/Berlin")

The exception in the WebAPI case is:
Unhandled exception. System.TimeZoneNotFoundException: The time zone ID 'Europe/Berlin' was not found on the local computer.
   at System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(String id)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Development\TimezoneTest\WebAPI\Program.cs:line 1


Both projects are part of the same solution, one created using the console template, the other using the webapi template. I run both of them in the IDE or using dotnet run.
I am aware of how to solve the problem. I'm interested in what the cause for the difference is, that results in an Exception in one case but doesn't in the other.

I'm also aware of a similar question and the accepted answer contains a hint about registry information, but I don't fully understand it, given that I'm running both apps locally on the same Windows laptop.

Are they reading timezones from different "databases"?
One from the registry and the other from ... what exactly? And what exactly causes the difference? (presence of some library?)

Which version(s) of .NET?

Hi Jens Hoffmann, I test it in my local by using vs2022, could you check my answer and give it a try. Please also help us to check if the issue occurs without using vs2022, many thanks

@MattJohnson-Pint I'm using .NET 8.0 (latest)

After deleting W. Europe Standard Time in my registry table, I can reproduce the issue.

Test Steps
Try to check W. Europe Standard Time is exist in your computer or not.
Path
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones


Solution
Create a timezone.reg file and excute it, then verify it in Registry Table.
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\W. Europe Standard Time]
"Display"="(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
"Dlt"="W. Europe Daylight Time"
"MUI_Display"="@tzres.dll,-320"
"MUI_Dlt"="@tzres.dll,-321"
"MUI_Std"="@tzres.dll,-322"
"Std"="W. Europe Standard Time"
"TZI"=hex:c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,0a,00,00,00,05,00,03,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,05,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

Double-click it and select yes.


Verify it.

Then restart your webapi project in vs2022.

Workaround
We also can use time zone ID W. Europe Standard Time to replace 'Europe/Berlin'.
var aa = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Europe/Berlin");
var ab = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");


Hi Jason, many thanks for your answer and the effort you put in. I need a bit of time to check this and will get back.

@JensHoffmann Sure., ga ahead. PLease inform us if it helps,many thanks
